# Set defaults for new content types

Tags: nodes

I have to make a lot of different new content types. It will save me some time if the defaults (promote to frontpage etc) are set to my preferences. How can I do this?

I hope you get my question

Comment: I'm just curious: 'A lot of new content types'? What so you use them for?

Comment: dont know, im not gonna use them ;) about 20 new content types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, if you want to change a content type default setting, just change it in :

> Administration » Structure » Content types » Edit a content type

Everything you change in the "global" content type settings will be default when you add a new node of this content type.

In the case of a Basic page, it will be this page (admin/structure/types/manage/page) :

[image]

Comment: I knew that, what I mean is: the DEFAULT settings. So when you make a NEW content type. The default settings are for example 'promote to frontpage' checked. I want this as default UNchecked. Of course I can change this afterwards, but thats not what I mean ;) Thanks for the extensive answer though

Comment: Oh I see, it's set in content_types.inc by variablet_get('node_options' .. Have a look on this topic http://drupal.org/node/105696